# Cannot save private key under Windows

Tags: windows, openssl

I have installed FireDeamon SSL 3 on a Windows 2022 VM client and it is running but if I try to create a private key, I cannot save it to a file.
`openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:xxxx -out server.pass.key` is not creating a file (at least I cannot find it).
If I execute the above command without `-out server.pass.key` the key will be displayed in the command window!

I have spend a lot of time to asked GOOGLE, but I haven't found any helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I have installed openSS-Win64!
This version of OpenSSL is saving the file in the current directory.
If you execute openssl in the CMD-Window and the command-Prompt show C:\Windows\system32, then the output file will be written into this directory.